# Does Battletag change concerns the numeric ID?

Tags: battle.net

Will my numeric ID change if I change my Battletag?

Let's say my battle tag is `tag#1234`. After I change it, will the numeric ID will stay the same, `tag2#1234`, or perhaps, will it generate a new numeric ID, `tag2#4321`?

Comment: Yes, a new number will be generated. You might be lucky to get the same again, but usually you get a new one. Especially with common names most of the numbers are already taken, so you actually have to get a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. The number that you see next to your name is just a hashing number. Long story short, it's just to make sure that, if you do have the same battletag as someone else, people are still able to add the right person and that there are still a way to distinguish you from others.

So changing your name will change your "hashing number" since there might already be a 'NewName'#'YourCurrentNumber'.

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/954721-starcraft-ii-heart-of-the-swarm/66202703

Comment: Can confirm, I recently changed my tag and the # went from something like 1738 to 11838.